# Mysql FullText index searching issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySql **FullText** indexing to search data from database.

Here is the `query`

```
$search_input_text = 'the_string_to_be_search';
$searchArray = explode(" ", $search_input_text);
$query="SELECT * FROM car_details
        WHERE  MATCH (car_trim) AGAINST ('";
foreach ($searchArray as $word) {
    $query .= "+".$word."* ";
}
$query .= "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

The query is executing fine but it has a bug, if you look at the **column name** you will find *car_trim* which is inside the **MATCH()** function. The column has only 3 different types of values in the database which are 'T5', 'T6' and 'T5 premier'.

When I type '**Premier**' in the search bar and hit Enter, it fetches the results whose values contain the word '`Premier`'. But when I type **T5** or **T6** , it returns an empty record. Please be sure that there are lots of records with car_trim='T5', car_trim='T6' or car_trim='T5 Premier'

I am not getting that what can be the problem with the strings `T5` and `T6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has two key parameters when using full text search (and a few other important ones).  The key parameters are the minimum word length and the stop words list.  In short, MySQL ignores words that are less than 3 or 4 characters (depending on the storage engine) or that are in the stop word list.

Your examples ("T5" and "T6") are too short -- based on the parameter defaults.

Some other configuration parameters might be of interest, such as the maximum word length and the characters that are valid for words.

You can change the parameters for full text indexing and re-build the index.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) is a good place to start in understanding this.

Comment: Ohh that's the matter, thank you @Gordon for making me aware of this.